# CDF player internet access config

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-cdf, wolfram-cdf

Where is the internet access configuration of the CDF Player?

On Mathematica, if I tell it to use the same config as the system, it doesn't work. If I write my-self this same config, it works.

I want to do the same on the CDF Player (it says it can't find the internet). Where's the "preferences"?

Thank you,

Comment: Could you explain what config are you writing?

Comment: I mean the proxy settings, that on Mathematica we find it on edit->preferences->internet connectivity

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that CDF player is a crippled version of Mathematica, with limited possibilities to access online data. Computable data that you get from Wolfram's servers with, for instance, `WeatherData` seems to be accessible, but importing websites as html using `Import` isn't possible. You might need [Player Pro](http://www.wolfram.com/products/playerpro/) for this.

Comment: It's exactly WeatherData that I'm using. I think the problem is that the player isn't finding internet, but I don't know where I can configure the proxy settings.

Comment: @user655673 Do you use a personal firewall? Does your office use a firewall?

Comment: Yes. I'm in the company network, passing thru a firewall. But I can configure Mathematica to work, configuring the proxy and port on mathematica->edit->preferences->internet connectivity.  I wanted to do the same on the player... How is the Player supposed to work inside a company firewall?

Comment: @user655673 I assume it uses the internet settings from either internet explorer of firefox, probably the one that is set as default browser. Might it be that you have more browsers on your system?

Comment: @user655673 I originally thought that your firewall might use NTLM authentication, a relative old MS method not supported in Mathematica. I've had that problem in my office. I (partly) solved this with this proxy software: http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/. But I don't think this causes your problem as it would prevent both Mathematica an Player from working correctly.

Comment: I have ie and firefox. Both access the internet with no problem. Searched for the player internet config both on files, and on the registry. Nothing...

Comment: @user655673 I did the same. Have been looking into all the init.m files to see if Mathematica's proxy settings appear there. Also watched what happens if I set proxy settings in mma with process monitor but did not see much useful. Player has an init.m file too. Perhaps you could put the setting there? Or have you tried  `SetInternetProxy` in your program?

Comment: Tried everything. It even seems like the Player doesn't take SetInternetProxy into consideration.
Can someone from Wolfram please help us?

Comment: @Sjoerd I see you are now doing Project Euler.  I hope you enjoy it.  Good luck!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You made me do it... What's your timing on prob14, BTW?

Comment: @Sjoerd, 12 seconds, 76 MB RAM.  Shall I email you a list of the problems I have solved, so you know which ones me may discuss in fair play?

Comment: @Please do. 12 secs; hmmm, mine took 140 secs. I didn't use memoization because I was afraid of the memory usage. I guess you did, right?